# retrieve Service Recovery options of a particular service using wmi

Tags: windows-services, wmi

is it possible to retrieve service recovery options as shown in service property windows like (First failure, Second failure, Subsequent failure information) using wmi??
and also for the password of a user account for a particular service in wmi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cannot get any password related information from the wmi. and also we cannot get the recovery tab details (shows in services.msc ) . if we need to get recovery details we may use the advapi32.dll [queryserviceconfig2()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/queryserviceconfig.html).